# Efficient way of code reuse for finding the largest prime factor

Tags: python, optimization, primes, python-3.x

I was doing timing with variations of function `largest_prime_factor`. I was able to write a better one `largest_prime_factor2`. There were some repetitions in the new function so I wrote another function `largest_prime_factor3`.

I thought the 3rd one has to be faster than the 2nd because I broke it up into more functions but it wasn't faster but slower.

- I wanted to know whether my method of code reuse is good or not?
- Is there a better way of reusing code in Python?
- Did I miss something due to which the new function became slower?

My functions alongwith the `testing()` function used to test all three.

```
def largest_prime_factor(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    ans = 0
    if num % 2 == 0:
        ans = 2
        num /= 2
        while num % 2 == 0:
            num /= 2

    i = 3
    while i <= num:
        if num % i == 0:
            ans = i
            num /= i
            while num % i == 0:
                num /= i

        i += 2

    return ans

def largest_prime_factor2(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''    
    ans = 0
    if num % 2:
        pass
    else:
        ans = 2
        while True:
            num //= 2
            if num % 2:
                break

    i = 3
    while i <= num:
        if num % i:
            pass
        else:
            ans = i
            while True:
                num //= i
                if num % i:
                    break

        i += 2

    return ans

def largest_prime_factor3(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    def check(j):
        nonlocal ans
        nonlocal num
        if num % j:
            return
        ans = j
        while True:
            num //= j
            if num % j:
                return
    ans = 0
    check(2)
    i = 3
    while i <= num:
        check(i)
        i += 2

    return ans

def testing():
    from timeit import Timer
    import random

    def tests(f, times):
        def test1(f):
            f(random.randint(1, 1000))
        def test2(f):
            f(random.randint(100000, 1000000))

        print(f.__name__)
        print(Timer(lambda: test1(f)).timeit(number = times))
        print(Timer(lambda: test2(f)).timeit(number = times//10))
        print()


    tests(largest_prime_factor, 10000)
    tests(largest_prime_factor2, 10000)
    tests(largest_prime_factor3, 10000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testing()
```

The timing results that I found:

> ```
> largest_prime_factor
> 0.338549207387318
> 16.599112750324068
>
> largest_prime_factor2
> 0.21575289594063918
> 12.086949738861868
>
> largest_prime_factor3
> 0.36032199674939847
> 18.893444539398857
> ```

This format of results is produced by the `testing` function. See that for details.

Comment: As this question is about time efficiency any discussions for this can take place in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9695/discussion-about-timing-in-python). Please use this to avoid extended discussions.

Comment: "I thought the 3rd one has to be faster than the 2nd because I broke it up into more functions but it wasn't faster but slower. " Why would you think that? Using function call instead of "inlining the code" can *only* produce a slowdown. Depending on the interpreter/compiler the code might be optimized to obtain the same efficiency as the inlined version, otherwise you end up with function-call overhead which means *slower* code. This is especially true in python where the interpreter doesn't do this kind of optimization and function calls are relatively expensive.

Comment: I know that making function calls costs performance in C but I came upon that [code runs faster in functions in case of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function). That led me to think that. Or is it incorrect? I am a newbie so I don't know how to use that for analyzing my code so I asked here what did I miss that led to performance lag. Anyways, is there a better way to inline the code in the case of 3rd function? That would improve readability and should also improve performance.

Comment: The code *doesn't* run faster in functions. The problem is that accessing *global* variables is slower than accessing local ones. This implies that a loop **at the top level** will be slow, because all variables all global and require the slow access. In your case the code that you put inside the `check` function was already inside a function, hence it was already using the fast local lookup.

Comment: I think I understand that now. Is there any alternative way to inline the code without losing performance?

Comment: In general no. In your example you had to copy the loop to special case `2`. But you can create an iterable that first yields 2 and then only the odd numbers. For example using `itertools.chain`: `for i in it.chain([2], range(3, num, 2)): ...` would do what you want.  (Last remark: instead of `while True` you could use `while n % i == 0` and remove the `break`).

Comment: I'll try using `itertools` as you have suggested. About the second suggestion about using the condition in the `while` loop I have timed that. It is slower.

Comment: Did you remove the `if` when timing that? `for i in range(3, num, 2): while n %i == 0: ... n //= i`. Also, do not obsess to much about timing. Readable code is *much better* than a code that take 0.1 msec less. Having `while True`s around doesn't make code readable.

Comment: By the way: you are considering only micro-optimizations when you could optimize the number of iterations in a much more significant way. You don't have to check numbers over `sqrt(n)` since they cannot be factors of `n`. the only case is when `n` is prime).

Comment: To everyone. Let us continue this discussion in this [chat room for discussion about timing in Python](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9695/discussion-about-timing-in-python) as it going too long. Please post further comments there.

Comment: @Bakuriu Make your comments a proper answer. That really helped me. The timing had huge improvements.

Comment: @Bakuriu Can you make that an answer? I have been waiting to accept your answer. Or should I write it myself?

Comment: I wrote my answer. Note that my previous comment wasn't entirely true. A number *can* have a factor bigger than the square root, but it can have only once such factor. See my answer for the final correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid code duplication and the performance regression that you get when putting that code into a function you can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools as it

def largest_prime_factor(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    ans = num
    for div in it.chain([2], range(3, num, 2)):
        while not num % div:
            num //= div
            ans = div
    return ans
```

To improve performances in a significant way you can reduce the number of iterations noting that you don't have to check factors bigger than `sqrt(num)`, since if `num` isn't a prime, then it can have at most one prime factor bigger than its square root(otherwise, if `p` and `q` where prime factors bigger than `sqrt(n)` you'd get that `n = A * p *q > A * sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = A * n > n` which cannot be true when `A != 1`).

This leads to:

```
def largest_prime_factor(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    ans = num
    sqrt_num = int(num**.5)
    for div in it.chain([2], range(3, sqrt_num + 1, 2)):
        while not num % div:
            num //= div
            ans = div
    return ans if num == 1 else num
```

Note that, at the end of the `for` loop, the value of `num` is 1 if all its prime factors were smaller than the square root, otherwise it is equal to the only prime factor bigger than the square root.

Sample run:

```
In [34]: list(map(largest_prime_factor, range(2, 25)))
Out[34]: [2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2, 3, 5, 11, 3, 13, 7, 5, 2, 17, 3, 19, 5, 7, 11, 23, 3]
```

---

In fact we can further optimize the code noting that, whenever `num` becomes `1` inside the `for` loop we can safely `break` out of it(while the current code tries all the other factors up to `sqrt(n)` anyway).

```
def largest_prime_factor(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    ans = num
    sqrt_num = int(num**.5)
    for div in it.chain([2], range(3, sqrt_num + 1, 2)):
        while not num % div:
            num //= div
            ans = div
        if div > num // div:
            return ans
    return num
```

We could also do something like:

```
def largest_prime_factor(num):
    '''returns the largest prime factor of a number'''
    ans = num
    sqrt_num = int(num**.5)
    candidates = it.chain([2], range(3, sqrt_num + 1, 2))
    for div in it.takewhile(lambda div: div <= num // div, candidates):
        while not num % div:
            num //= div
            ans = div
    return max(ans, num)
```

However this last version does a function call for each iteration and it will be *slightly* slower.

Comment: I figured that there is a bigger number. There is slight formatting problem in the beginning of the question when importing `itertools`. Also when `sqrt_num = int(num**.5) + 1` then you don't need the `+ 1` in the range. Redundant. Please fix that

Comment: @AseemBansal Fixed.

Comment: largest prime factor of (2^200 * 9) is 3. To find this, the maximal divisor to try by is 3, not (3 * 2^100). :)

Comment: welcome; your code isn't right still though. What about (2^100 * 10000000019)? What is the biggest divisor to consider?

Comment: Actually your new solution can be improved. That is a function so if num is 1 you don't need to break. You can just return. Then you can take out the condition from the return statement.

Comment: This solution can be good for really big numbers but wouldn't it be bad for small numbers? Perhaps  check the range of the number and call different helper functions. Also placing any arithmetic in `range` slows it down slightly. The `+1` should be placed when `sqrt_num` is calculated.

Comment: @AseemBansal It doesn't make any difference where you put the `+1`. `range` is a function like any other, which means all its arguments are evaluated *once* when the function is called. @WillNess In that case I don't see how the code could see where to stop. It wouldn't be too hard to implement Miller-Rabin and do a fast check for primality at every iteration and stop whenever it fails, but it seems an overkill to me.

Comment: @WillNess Just out of curiosity, why aren't you posting an answer?

Comment: @AseemBansal if this is almost right, easier to correct it here.

Comment: @AseemBansal You should read also about [`Fermat's factorization method`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) which, with a bit more work, achieves better performance for numbers with big prime factors.

Comment: @Bakuriu just use a `while` loop, nothing fancy, with stop condition `divisor <= number / divisor`. Increment divisor by 2, starting from 3. Test divisor=2 separately. Inside the loop have `number /= divisor` like you have now. -- (BTW, `while not num % div:` is *very* counter-intuitive, to me. :) I'd write `while num % div == 0:`).

Comment: @WillNess I see, changed; now it should be as fast as possible for a simple implementation. Regardin the rest I don't see why should I use a `while` loop where a `for` will do(note that in python using a `while` *will* decrease performances, even though in this case, hopefully, the operations inside the loop should take most of the time). Also the OP specifically asked how to do this *without* testing `2` separately. Regarding the `not`: it's common practice in python to use `not` or simply `if expression` to check for truth values(e.g. `if some_sequence:` means `some_sequence` isn't empty.

Comment: @Bakuriu you were totally right about the `while` vs `for`! now I know, for sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, splitting your code into different smaller functions is a good idea as it makes things easier to read, to reuse and to test.

However, this comes at a (cheap) price as far as performances are concerned because functions calls are not for free (nor are function definitions).

Now, for additional advices, whenever you want to compare performances of functions, it might also be a good idea to return what they compare. It's not good having a fast function if it doesn't return the right thing. By using `assert`, you could ensure you get notified quickly whenever something goes wrong.

This being said, I'd like to run and comment your code but I don't have a python3 handy and it seems that it is the version you are using so I'll try to do this later :-)

Comment: I am not using many features of Python3. You just need to  change the `print` in the `testing` function. Maybe the nested function in that also. Everything else is same. Otherwise you can use http://ideone.com/ if you want.

Comment: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) is your friend :-) The code: http://ideone.com/565hyx (Note that I divided the number of tests by 100.)

Comment: @Lstor Making the numbers too small would give wrong results. the large numbers were the reason it is giving reproducible results. Instead just changing the `testing` function should suffice. Not much Python3 in this.

Comment: @AseemBansal I fully agree, and larger numbers are definitely better. But ideone.com has a time limitation, and the purpose of running the code there is *running* it, not *timing* it.

Comment: Thanks guys, `nonlocal` was actually the place making my python2.x interpreter sad ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice about `assert`. About function calls costing performance then what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)?

Comment: Interesting link!

Comment: @Josay I'll be waiting to hear back from you.